# Bandgap Reference 1.25V

Tags: analog

[image]

[Taken from Razavi's Design of Analog CMOS IC]

Hi, I'm just wondering, how does he get the 1.25V in 12.21?

Comment: I think the answer is very obvious, why don't you just replace VBE and VT with their values to get the approximate 1.25V?

Comment: @dirac16 Vt = kT/q. How do you determine what temperature to evaluate it at. Similarly, what is the value of Vbe?

Comment: Somewhere earlier in the book he will have said what values he considers typical. Temperature is probably between 290 and 295 K, and Vt is probably 25 or 26 mV.

Comment: Hmm. I see. One more thing, in the first paragraph, he writes "Since at room temperature,  dVbe/dT = -1.5mV/K." That's seems a bit weird to me. Why is that at room temperature? Why did he mention that? Does that mean that the rate of change of Vbe with temperature depnds on the temperature??? Then surely, this circuit is only temperature independeant at one particular temperature????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He multiplies the value of the thermal voltage, \$V_T\$, by 17.2 and then adds the nominal base-emitter voltage, \$V_{BE}\$. Both \$V_T\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ will have been discussed at length in previous paragraphs.

Comment: What do you mean by nominal base-emitter voltage?

Comment: It is inconceivable to me that \$V_{BE}\$ is not discussed at great length in an earlier part of the book. I am referring to the typical value of \$V_{BE}\$ when that junction is forward biased.